# FormCollection not populated on ajax POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I have an ajax POST request that is supposed to be submitting data to an ASP.NET MVC action. This works fine 95% of the time but every so often, for whatever reason, my FormCollection is empty and the application errors out as a result.

I would have included the raw request values however I haven't been able to reproduce this myself.

My ajax call looks like this:

```
var data = {};
data.Property = 123; // etc

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(viewModel) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

**What would cause the FormCollection to intermittently be empty on the ajax POST?**

I have suspected things like session timeouts and the like but I would expect that to error out before I get in to the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you seem to be sending a JSON request (`JSON.stringify(data)`). This is not supported out of the box in ASP.NET MVC 2. It is in ASP.NET MVC 3 that a `JsonValueProviderFactory` was introduced. You may take a look at the [following article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) which explains in more details JSON requests in ASP.NET MVC.

Also everytime you want to send a JSON request you should set the proper content type using the `contentType` parameter:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

and last but not least I would recommend you to use view models instead of relying on some weakly typed structures such as FormCollection in your controller actions and having to write plumbing code.

---

UPDATE:

`FormCollection` is a key/value pair collection. So if you want to use it (despite my recommendation against it) you should not use a JSON request. You should use a normal key value request. So remove the JSON.stringify from your AJAX request and remove the contentType: 'application/json' parameter as well. There's really no point in using weakly typed key/value pair collection with JSON objects.

Comment: Had already read that article and subsequently added JsonValueProviderFactory - which is why it's working most of the time. I had also tried adding contentType in, however then the FormCollection is _never_ populated, even though post data is being sent correctly looking at the raw http request. Is this a 'feature' in MVC?

Comment: @ajbeaven, what FormCollection? Don't use any FormCollection. Define a view model that corresponds to this JSON object and have your controller action take a view model as argument.

Comment: Regardless of your thoughts around FormCollections, I think there is some benefit for the SO community in addressing my question, particularly if it's a bug in MVC and particularly when many tutorials out then use FormCollections to retrieve posted form values (especially when there are not many values posted). All the same, I've gone with your suggestion :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ajbeaven, FOrmCollection is a key/value pair collection. So if you want to use it (despite my recommendation against it) you should not use a JSON request. You should use a normal key value request. So remove the JSON.stringify from your AJAX request and remove the `contentType: 'application/json'` parameter as well. There's really no point in using weakly typed key/value pair collection with JSON objects.

Comment: Update you question with your last comment and I'll mark as the answer.